# Delete 5 years old records from a table and its dependencies i.e. parent and child tables both in Oracle using query or procedure

Tags: oracle

How to 5 years old records from a table and its dependencies i.e. parent and child tables both in Oracle using query or procedure.
I tried using the dateadd command of oracle but it only delete records from main table and not from its child table. 
Assume table A is main table and B&C are child tables. How can we delete records from A as well as B&C that are 5 yrs old.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to first delete child tables by joining the child tables with parent table
2. Once child table is deleted, delete the parent table

You can either have a procedure or you can also delete using simple queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 separate `DELETE` and just need to use the query on A using `ADD_MONTHS`, take its PK and delete from B then C then A using that PKS as follows:

```
DELETE FROM B 
WHERE A_FK IN (SELECT A_PK FROM A WHERE DATECOLUMN <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -60));

DELETE FROM C 
WHERE A_FK IN (SELECT A_PK FROM A WHERE DATECOLUMN <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -60));

DELETE FROM A WHERE DATECOLUMN <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -60);
```